# How to create mesh on canvas 3D and destroy it after x second?

Tags: javascript

Actually I just want to move my object3D position using external API, but it seems this module doesn't provide dynamic changes but I have to re-create the mesh and destroy it.
The code below just destroys the new mesh I created without giving it any delay to load.

```
var numb = 0;
  setInterval(function () {
    const changes = numb++;
    const newId = changes.toString();
    const workerModel = new Mesh(viewer.scene, {
      id: newId,
      isModel: true,
      geometry: new ReadableGeometry(
        viewer.scene,
        buildSphereGeometry({
          heightSegments: 60,
          widthSegments: 60,
        })
      ),
      scale: [0.3, 1.5, 0.3],
      position: [changes, 1, 0],
      material: new PhongMaterial(viewer.scene, {
        diffuse: [0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
      }),
    });
    workerModel.destroy();
    
  }, 2000);
```

Comment: The code you have shared is no `three.js` code. Meshes and mateirals are created differently and  `ReadableGeometry` is no class of the project. What software are you using?

Comment: @Mugen87 yes its not THREE.js , it is Xeokit BIM viewer. My question is more like javascript question. How to destroy last object  after x second ? when I create objects every second.